# Cordova file is not creating directory

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a cordova application that uses the file plugin, inside the app everything works fine, but the files that i use doesn't appear in File Explorer.

My class is:

```
function FileCordova () {

    this.createDir = function(dirName, callback) {

      App.db.fsSetup();
      if (App.db.hasFS()) {

            window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 0, function (f) {
              f.root.getDirectory(dirName, {create: true}, function (d) {
                  typeof callback === 'function' && callback(d.name, d.fullPath);
              },
              function(error, err2){
                console.log(error);
              });
            }, function(error,err2){
              console.log(error);
            });

        } else {
            typeof callback === 'function' && callback();
        }
    };

}
```

Inside the app de file appear, but I can't find in the root directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just recently had to do this in my app. I used the `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL()` method instead of `window.requestFileSystem()`:

```
var exportDirectory = "";
var subdir = "MySubdirectory";
// What directory should we place this in?
if (cordova.file.documentsDirectory !== null) {
    // iOS, OSX
    exportDirectory = cordova.file.documentsDirectory;
} else if (cordova.file.sharedDirectory !== null) {
    // BB10
    exportDirectory = cordova.file.sharedDirectory;
} else if (cordova.file.externalRootDirectory !== null) {
    // Android, BB10
    exportDirectory = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory;
} else {
    // iOS, Android, BlackBerry 10, windows
    exportDirectory = cordova.file.DataDirectory;
}

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(exportDirectory, function (directoryEntry) {
    console.log("Got directoryEntry. Attempting to open / create subdirectory:" + subdir);
    directoryEntry.getDirectory(subdir, {create: true}, function (subdirEntry) {
        subdirEntry.getFile(filename, {create: true}, function (fileEntry) {
            console.log("Got fileEntry for: " + filename);
            fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                console.log("Got fileWriter");
                // make your callback to write to the file here...
            }, exportFail);
        }, exportFail);
    }, exportFail);
}, exportFail);
```

Note, however, that the Android File Transfer utility did NOT refresh properly. I had to disconnect / reconnect my USB cable, and then the directory showed up. This might actually be your issue with File Explorer (i.e., check that before changing code).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the point is that your are saving the file inside the App Data Directory (Private), if you want to put in somewhere public (Allowing in that way to see it in the File Browser) you must review [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#where-to-store-files) docs and pick one public location, for example in `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory`